# Нужно написать автокликер в Android на Java

Tags: java, android

Есть 2 кнопки. И для каждой есть счётчик. Нужно,чтобы когда Switch ON(авто режим), автокликер рандомным образом кликал на кнопку до тех пор,пока на счётчике синей кнопки не наберется 3600 кликов(sleep 100мс).На скрине примерно так оно и должно выглядеть(принцип тот же).
Я только пару дней назад начал изучение разработки приложений под Андроид, поэтому указывайте на ошибки, будет интересно почитать.Я был бы очень благодарен за решение этой задачки.Всем спасибо)))

Вот код MainActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;

    private TextView text2;
    private Switch switch1;
    private TextView text4;
    private TextView text3;
    private TextView text5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonBlue);

        text2 = findViewById(R.id.textViewBlueScore);
        switch1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        text3 = findViewById(R.id.textViewRedScore);

        final int[] text4 = {0};
        final int[] text5 = {0};

        View.OnClickListener onClickListenerRed = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text5[0] += 1;
                text3.setText(text5[0] + "");
            }
        };
        View.OnClickListener onClickListenerBlue = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text4[0] += 1;
                text2.setText(text4[0] + "");
            }
        };
        button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerBlue);
        button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerRed);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Тебе лучше вывести обработчик нажатия на кнопку в отдельную функцию.

```
public void ButtonRedClick(View view) {
......
}
```

Соответственно, в xml файле в коде кнопки указываешь

```
android:onClick="ButtonRedClick"
```

И можешь вызывать нажатие программно откуда хочешь.